# Can't understand why this simple addition doesn't work when it does in the chrome console

Tags: javascript

```
function findTotalDistance(points, order){
    var sum = 0;
    //Linearly add the distances of every element in this order and return the value
    for (var i = 0; i < order.length - 1; i++){
        var distance = points[i][i+1] + points[i+1][i+2];
        sum = sum + distance;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I get returned a value of NaN for this despite when I run:

```
            var distance = points[i][i+1] + points[i+1][i+2];
```

in the chrome console it returns the expected value. points is a 2d array of integers, 4x4

Comment: `order.length - 1` combined with `[i+2]` means the index jumps out of the arrays bounds... Could you please explain what this code should do?

Comment: As is often the case, you can figure out what's going wrong by using the powerful debugger built into your browser or IDE. Step through the code statement by statement, watching variable values, etc.

Comment: I have 4 places on a map. So I created a 2d array with an array for each of the 4 locations. Each array contains the distance between itself and all 4 points. So the first entry in the first array is 0, because the distance from itself to itself is 0. The second entry in the second is zero for the same reason, and so on. I want to add the second element of the first array, with the third element of the second array, with the fourth element of the third array, etc. To get a combined route distance

Comment: Can you add an examples of the `points` and `orders` arrays? You problem have simple, one line solution. But i must see structure ot these arrays.

Comment: Try `var distance = Number(points[i][i+1]) + Number(points[i+1][i+2])`